# Var declaration in Lazarus

Tags: variables, sequence, declaration, freepascal, lazarus

I have encountered a strange behavior on the declaration of variables in lazaus (2.0.6)

If I declare variables using the following sequence, the program stops execution by giving SIGSEGV error, the error pops up, if I assign initial value into second field of TabCellContent var

```
TabReadActive: Boolean;
ShCol: Array[0..6] of Boolean;
TabCellContent: Array [0..6] of Array [1..50] of TCellContent;
```

But if I place the "TabReadActive" below the declaration of Array's the program is working normally without error

```
ShCol: Array[0..6] of Boolean;
TabCellContent: Array [0..6] of Array [1..50] of TCellContent;
TabReadActive: Boolean;
```

Is there someone who encountered same behavior? And what is the reason for this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "if I assign initial value into second field of TabCellContent var" or, preferably, show the code you use to do this.

Comment: Does this also happen with range checks enabled ?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the code that access the variables access out of bounds. Accessing arrays out of bounds leads to undefined behaviour. It is just a coincidence that the order in which you declare the variables changes that behaviour. But that's the nature of undefined behaviour. It is, well, undefined.

Enable range checking in your compiler options, and run your program through the debugger. This will identify the point in your code where you access the array out of bounds.